# Julia: be sure to use dev version of a package

Tags: julia

I'm developping a package that is also registered. So I have a version in my dev folder ("C:/Users//.julia/dev"), and I have also the most recent registered version installed as if I didn't develop it.
So my question is, how can I be sure to use the dev version when I need to ? 
It appears that if I don't remove the registered version, it only uses this version instead of the dev one, even so I add my dev path to the load path of Julia.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `Pkg.develop` and `Pkg.free` to move to and from development version of the package (or `dev` and `free` commands in pkg manager mode). Then you can use `Pkg.status` to see which version is currently active. Here is an example:

```
julia> Pkg.status("DataFrames")
    Status `C:\Users\bogum\.julia\environments\v1.2\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.19.4

julia> Pkg.develop("DataFrames")
[ Info: Path `C:\Users\bogum\.julia\dev\DataFrames` exists and looks like the correct package, using existing path
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `C:\Users\bogum\.julia\environments\v1.2\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] ↑ DataFrames v0.19.4 ⇒ v0.19.4+ [`C:\Users\bogum\.julia\dev\DataFrames`]
  Updating `C:\Users\bogum\.julia\environments\v1.2\Manifest.toml`
  [a93c6f00] ↑ DataFrames v0.19.4 ⇒ v0.19.4+ [`C:\Users\bogum\.julia\dev\DataFrames`]
  [9a8bc11e] + DataStreams v0.4.2

julia> Pkg.status("DataFrames")
    Status `C:\Users\bogum\.julia\environments\v1.2\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.19.4+ [`C:\Users\bogum\.julia\dev\DataFrames`]

julia> Pkg.free("DataFrames")
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `C:\Users\bogum\.julia\environments\v1.2\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] ↓ DataFrames v0.19.4+ [`C:\Users\bogum\.julia\dev\DataFrames`] ⇒ v0.19.4
  Updating `C:\Users\bogum\.julia\environments\v1.2\Manifest.toml`
  [a93c6f00] ↓ DataFrames v0.19.4+ [`C:\Users\bogum\.julia\dev\DataFrames`] ⇒ v0.19.4
  [9a8bc11e] - DataStreams v0.4.2

julia> Pkg.status("DataFrames")
    Status `C:\Users\bogum\.julia\environments\v1.2\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.19.4
```

As you can see in status result you have an information which version of the package is used.

See also:

- https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/dev/managing-packages/#Developing-packages-1 (about developing packages)
- https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/dev/managing-packages/#Adding-registered-packages-1 (about reading status output)

Comment: Thank you very much! It was not clear for me that `pkg.dev` just uses the version I already have in development. I thought it would overwrite it with the new version, i.e. always starting a fresh dev version from the registered one.

Comment: This is how I understand "Note the package manager will never touch any of the files at a tracked path." sentence from the docs :).

Comment: Ho OK. I wasn't sure what a tracked path was. I have still a lot of key words to learn I believe.